# Add statically object to ListModel

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I need to create a `ListModel`, that contains an object (string and bool inside) statically.
If I add to an empty `ListModel` element by using append - all works well.

```
property ListModel qwe: ListModel {}
var imageToAdd { value: "picture.png", imageType: 1 }

qwe.append({
    text: "TextToAdd",
    image: imageToADD,
    position: 1
})
// This works correct
```

But I need to create `ListModel` statically and it doesn't work.

```
ListModel {
    ListElement {
        text: "TextToAdd"
        image: { value: "Qwer.png", imageType: 1 }  // <-- This doesn't work
        position: 1
    }
}
```

How it should look like?

Comment: Do you have `var imageToADD { value: "picture.png" ... }` in your original code? `image` is an unused variable.

Comment: True, missed with names. Thank you, edited

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `ListElement` in Qt must have values of type `string`, `bool`, `numbers` or `enum`. More complex datatypes like hashmaps are not allowed.

You can read this deep down in the Qt 5.2 sourcecode: [qqmllistmodel.cpp](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/e895bc315f9959a5dad80a8f0bf7b73bced0bde1%3asrc/qml/types/qqmllistmodel.cpp#L2537). This didn't change since the [Qt 4.7 times](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qml-listelement.html).

> List elements are defined inside ListModel definitions, and represent items in a
>   list that will be displayed using ListView or Repeater items.
>
> List elements are defined like other QML elements except that they contain
>   a collection of *role* definitions instead of properties. Using the same
>   syntax as property definitions, roles both define how the data is accessed
>   and include the data itself.
>
> The names used for roles must begin with a lower-case letter and should be
>   common to all elements in a given model. Values must be simple constants; either
>   strings (quoted and optionally within a call to QT_TR_NOOP), boolean values
>   (true, false), numbers, or enumeration values (such as AlignText.AlignHCenter).

However, a `ListModel` seems to be capable to store all types defined in the ECMA-262 standard: The primitive types, which are `Undefined`, `Null`, `Boolean`, `Number`, and `String` as well as the `Object` type.

**Edit:** If you want to create the elements in QML, you have to rewrite your code to something like

```
ListModel {
    ListElement {
        text: "TextToAdd"
        imageValue: "Qwer.png"
        imageType: 1
        position: 1
    }
}
```

**Edit2:** Or you go the Javascript way. Create an empty model first and fill it on start

```
ListView {
    model: ListModel { id: qwe }
    delegate: ... 

    Component.onCompleted: {
        qwe.append({
            text: "Image 1",
            image: { value: "picture.png", imageType: 1 },
            position: 1
        });
        qwe.append({
            text: "Image 2",
            image: { value: "picture.png", imageType: 1 },
            position: 2
        });
        qwe.append({
            text: "Image 1",
            image: { value: "picture.png", imageType: 1 },
            position: 3
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, check the EDIT of my answer above.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer, but check my first post. Image there is object with 2 fields inside and it's not the same as in your example. If i append to ListModel my image object - i can use something like: "ListModelName.get(0).image.value" I need to create same list model, but without using "append" - create it statically

Comment: Okay, if you can't change the structure of your data, you have to go with javascript. Check the second edit for that. These are the only two solutions without using custom components.

Answer (score 2):

```
model: ListModel {
    ListElement {
        name: "My Name"
        image: ListElement {
            src: "My src"
        }
    }
}
```

You can access it in for example a delegate:

```
image.get(0).src
```

I would asume you should be able to access it via image.src but that doesn't work...